# Push notifications aren't working on iOS 7 but working on iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I have an app where i am sending push notifications using APNS. I have configured notifications in app using following code

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_8_0 //__IPHONE_8_0 is not    defined in old xcode (==0). Then use 80000

    NSLog(@"registerForPushNotification: For iOS >= 8.0");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
     [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
      (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                       categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
#endif
}
else {
    NSLog(@"registerForPushNotification: For iOS < 8.0");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

What I found id notifications are working with iOS 8 and later devices but on iOS7 device it done even ask for notifications enabling but it appears under notification settings. What is going wrong ?

Comment: Have you received device token for both ios versions ?

Comment: @Surjeet yes i m receiving token for both and on iOS 8 it works , tried on iPad 2 as well as iPhone 4

Comment: Can you check for any error in the following method?
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err

Comment: no doesn't return any error

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]    respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    } else {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

#else

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

#endif
```

Comment: oh well tried that one as well in earlier code didn't work , i think that line is for anything greater than os 8 and here it already works on 8

Answer (score 0):

Go for the below one, This code is tested recently and push notification working perfectly.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

} //Register for notifications..
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                             |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
#endif
    {
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }
```